# Jump to ID tags in X direction

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm currently using this here to jump to an id tag on the page, although I need to be able to jump to the X direction as well if possible that would be great?

So basically I just want a button that will scroll to a div thats placed on the x direction of a page the same as it would vertically :)

```
//anchors
  function filterPath(string) {
    return string
      .replace(/^\//,'')
      .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
      .replace(/\/$/,'');
  }

  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    if ( filterPath(location.pathname) == filterPath(this.pathname)
    && location.hostname == this.hostname
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
      var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
       if ($target) {
         var targetOffset = $target.offset().top + 90;
         $(this).click(function() {
           $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 600);
           return false;
         });         
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach that seems to work:

```
$('a').click(
    function(e){
        // prevents the default 'jump'
        e.preventDefault();
        // caches the href of the clicked link
        var href = this.href,
            // takes the href, splits off the '#' character (and anything before it)
            // and uses that to find the id of the target element.
            target = $('#' + href.substring(href.indexOf('#') + 1)),
            // finds, and caches the offsets
            offsets = target.offset(),
            // finds the offset of the top of the element (relative to the page)
            top = offsets.top,
            left = offsets.left;
        // animates the movement to the top, and the left, position of the target
        $('body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop : top,
            scrollLeft : left
        }, 1000);
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XHEZy/6/).

Revised the above, to use `split()` instead of `substring()`:

```
$('a').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = this.href,
            // as above, but more concise
            target = $('#' + href.split('#')[1]),
            offsets = target.offset(),
            top = offsets.top,
            left = offsets.left;
        $('body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop : top,
            scrollLeft : left
        }, 1000);
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XHEZy/5/).

And, if you wanted to have two distinct scroll events, this version would help with that:

```
$('a').click(
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $('#' + this.href.split('#')[1]),
            offsets = target.offset(),
            top = offsets.top,
            left = offsets.left;
        $('body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: top
        }, 1000, function() {
            $(this).animate({
                scrollLeft: left
            }, 1000);
        });
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XHEZy/4/).

Comment: You should remove hash in the top ul id attribute in your fiddle.

Comment: Oh, *dear Lord*...I can't believe I didn't *see* that >.< Thanks! (and edited! To correct for blindness. And, possibly, silliness. Sigh.)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question :)
http://jsfiddle.net/QWLEW/

```
​<div style="width: 1500px; overflow: visible;">
    <a href="#foo">Goto div</a>
    <div id="foo" style="width: 100px; position:absolute; left: 1000px;">Here Iam</div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

When you click on the link, the page will jump to the div with id foo.

And with animation. (edited your code)
It's now also going to it's horizontal position. I removed the +90 px, because I do not know, what you're trying to achieve with that.

http://jsfiddle.net/g47bn/

```
//anchors
  function filterPath(string) {
    return string
      .replace(/^\//,'')
      .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
      .replace(/\/$/,'');
  }

  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    if ( filterPath(location.pathname) == filterPath(this.pathname)
    && location.hostname == this.hostname
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
      var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
       if ($target) {
         $(this).click(function() {
             //Use offset top and left to go to the divs position
             $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $target.offset().top, scrollLeft: $target.offset().left}, 600);
           return false;
         });         
      }
    }
  });​
```

If you only want to scroll top or left, remove the other ptoperty form here.

$('html, body').animate({**scrollTop: $target.offset().top, scrollLeft: $target.offset().left**}, 600);

Comment: I don't think It does :( I basically i want this effect :http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/jquery_internal_animation_scrolling/#contact 

But on the x direction not y :(

Comment: Edited my post. Is that, what you're looking for?

Comment: That is :)))))) But is there a way to make it do both if it needs to?

Comment: Edited the post, so you can see how to scroll only top or left. If it's cool, please vote for it :)

Comment: I Guys, You both do what I have described, but is there a way so that it animates from top and left at the same time? not scroll left, then scroll down?

Comment: $('a').click(
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $('#' + this.href.split('#')[1]),
            offsets = target.offset(),
            top = offsets.top,
            left = offsets.left;
        $('body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: top,
            scrollLeft: left
        }, 1000
        );
    });

I Think I've done it correctly with this? ​